# I need to make a slightly-less-than-\fullcite

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I am attempting to adapt the [tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) style to typeset a Ph.D dissertation. The style currently uses the natbib/bibentry package to insert full-text citations as numbered side-notes, and also emits a full bibliography at the end of the document.  I would like to modify the document to use a shorter cite format (showing "et al" rather than full author list; removing URLs/DOIs/etc) for these side-note citations, but retain the full citation at the end of the document.  I'm also leaning heavily towards using biblatex instead of bibtex, for a variety of reasons.

So the question:  is it possible to create a custom, abbreviated citation style and instruct biblatex to use it in some places, and the primary/standard style in the main bib? I don't mind defining a new command (it's not necessary to redefine `\fullcite`, I'd rather use `\abbrevcite` or something).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to define custom cite commands, but just different settings for citations v. bibliographies. For showing "et al" in citations simply use the package options `maxbibnames` and `maxcitenames`; for removing certain fields only in citations use `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\clearfield`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/510},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \footfullcite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I needed to create this compressed citation style as a distinct cite command that would work independent of `\AtEveryCitekey` changes and the selected citation style, would you reccomend starting with `DeclareCiteCommand`?  I've been reading about it in the documentation and looking for demos, but I haven't convinced myself that this is the command that will do it.